# Update filtered values in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have array with data, like:

```
$scope.fathersArr = [
    { name: 'Joe', children:
         [
             { name:'Ammy' },
             { name:'Jane'},
             { name:'Honey'}
         ]
    },
    { name: 'Joe', children:
         [
             { name:'Tonny' },
             { name:'Katty'},
             { name:'Jonny'}
         ]
    }
];
```

I need get value from array, I filtered it like:

```
$scope.bestFather = $filter('filter')($scope.fathersArr, { name: 'Make'})[0];
```

I render data in like:

```
<li ng-repeat='child in bestFather.children'>{{child.name}}</li>
```

When I update `$scope.fathersArr`, my filtered value not updating.
I think, that `$filter` not support two way binding. So how I can update my filtered value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.bestFather is not re-evaluated automatically. You need to add a watch on $scope.fathersArr and then perform the filtering again to update the value.

```
$scope.$watch('fathersArr', function onFathersArrayChanged(fathersArr){
    $scope.bestFather = $filter('filter')(fathersArr, { name: 'Make'})[0];
});
```

I'm curious why you do not use the filter in your template though. It will be re-evaluated automatically for you.

Comment: It's really bad. Maybe angular present best way for finding in array?

Comment: I use `$scope.bestFather` also in controller, so I need filter it in controller. Maybe I can get `$scope.bestFather` by name without `$filter` ?